# AWS API Gateway - to use with AWS EC2 Endpoint or AWS Lambda?

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, mobile, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I need to create a  API where the Vendors will push the data to the server using REST calls and this data needs to further pushed to a user on mobile app(using Websocket guessing as of now) to whom the data belongs.

For Vendors to use REST API  : I need to check the Vendor credential and Write that data to DB.

I am keen to know what approach should I use ? Should I use AWS API Gateway which can help for security and scalability.

and while using AWS API Gateway - what would be a better approach to have EC2 Endpoint or Lambda Endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Using EC2 vs Lambda depends on how you want to design your services and specific use cases. Going serverless is a trend these days, but you do not need to go serverless, just for the sake of being serverless.

For your use case, If the REST API you will expose updates a Database, let's say RDS, Lambda function probably is not an ideal choice. As you will need to open a connection every time the lambda function is invoked. Moreover, if you are running the lambda in a NO VPC config, You will need to publicly expose your RDS port. If its DynamoDB, it works out well.

But again, you want to push out the update to Mobile apps over say web sockets. You definitely need a WebSocket Server somewhere, and I guess its EC2.

You may design your application in way such that all your business logic resides in the lambda functions, updates the DB, posts a message to an SQS queue. The WebSocket server can then pick up messages from the SQS queue and post updates. This decouples your application architecture. This is just one approach and wont scale horizontally out of the box.

OR - You may choose to put everything in one EC2 instance, expose a REST API that updates the DB and also posts updates to the WebSocket connection.

Comment: Thank you Yeshodhan. Since, I need to use RDS - it looks Lambda is not an option. So, I can go with EC2 instances where I can use 1 EC2 for API handling which will then post the message on SQS queue and there can be another EC2 instance which can deal with the Websocket communication with the users. 

I see one trick here : this is leading to a problem where how will I identify which EC2 device reads from SQS and the mobile user if is connected to the same EC2 device only then it will be able to transfer (when we try to scale)

Comment: Or I could use a hashing logic where the API call will be handled by the same EC2 device which is also connected to the user mobile .
Will the AWS API Gateway allow to use such logic to divert the API Calls to respective EC2 device depending upon username or vendor name.

Comment: *"For your use case, If the REST API you will expose updates a Database, let's say RDS, Lambda function probably is not an ideal choice. As you will need to open a connection every time the lambda function is invoked."*  Not necessarily. A lambda container can hold its RDS connection for reuse on its next invocation.  Easily done in Node, at least, with [`context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html) and a connection established outside the handler sub.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Aws recently raised lambda concurrent limit to 1000. Does that mean you want to have 1000 concurrents to the DB? How to go about gracefully shutting down the connection?

Comment: @jitenshah API gateway can simply help you with routing your API. You will need to manage your own app state using elasticache or dynamodb or even RDS.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I can try a quick prototype to check. What design would you suggest for my question : EC2 Endpoint or Lambda Endpoint - I will have to use RDS.

Comment: @jitenshah my inclination would be EC2, with HAProxy rather than API Gateway for access control and rate limiting, but that is based less on the merits of the various options and more on the fact that these are the technologies with which I am most familiar, and the fact that servers need to be involved of necessity, to terminate the web sockets.

Comment: I spoke to AWS Solution Architects and quoting his reply : 

"The Lambda containers are re-used where possible. This would mean that the container on which the Lambda runs will be frozen and re-used if the lambda is invoked again within a timeframe(there are no exact metrics around this timeframe as of now. It's best to not make any assumptions on this time-frame while developing the application.)"

Comment: Continuing to previous reply from AWS Solution Architect : 

"Coming to the best practice, from what I can tell, it's best not to handle the db connections directly in Lambda. Rather, you would use a connection pooling service which will manage the connections for you and will 'lend' these connections to Lambda as and when required. You can look at pgbouncer - https://pgbouncer.github.io"